# How do I get a dynamically configured DataSource property in a Spring Boot Library Project at runtime?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a multi-module project, consider A as my library project and B as an implementation project that imports A. Now my DataSource is configured in B using `@Configuration` and `getDataSource()` method dynamically. I want to access a property from this dynamically configured DataSource in project A from project B. I tried using `@ConfigurationProperties` but it is not possible. Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Spring bean wiring should do the trick at runtime. Did you mark your bean from B as `@Primary`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While configuring your DataSource, add a System property like `System.setProperty("key", value);` and access it in your library like `System.getProperty("key");`

Answer (score 0):

Consider using annotations like [@Primary](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-primary) or [@Qualifier](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-qualifier-annotation).

Answer (score 0):

You could try inject Environment into this service:

`private Environment env;`

and then

`env.getProperty("b.datasource.url");`

or inject ApplicationContext:

`private ApplicationContext context;`

and then get whole bean:

`context.getBean(DataSource.class);`

or by name:

`context.getBean("BDataSource"); // <- you need to know proper bean name`